# Implemet GestureDetector for videoview

Tags: android, gesturedetector

I want to implement a GestureDector for videoview insted for an activity.Is there any way?Plase provide some help

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a GestureDetector inside your view passing your View's getContext() to it. There are many examples related to pinch zoom and they do that.